# Adding values to nested dictionary when key exists

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to generate a dictionary of IDs per year per UID, but am struggling to add additional IDs to the nested year/ID dictionary when the year key is already present:

```
    Dim lstUID_Year_ID As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer))
    Dim intID As Integer = [some ID value taken from dataset according to other variables]

                    For Each a As [information] In [dataset]
                        If lstUID_Year_ID.ContainsKey(a.UID) Then
                            If lstUID_Year_ID(a.UID).ContainsKey(a.Year) Then
                                If Not lstUID_Year_ID(a.UID).Item(a.Year) = intID Then
'This is where I want to add another value to UID>Year
                                End If
                            Else
                                lstUID_Year_ID(a.UID).Add(a.Year, intID)
                            End If
                        Else
                            lstUID_Year_ID.Add(a.UID, New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer))
                            lstUID_Year_ID(a.UID).Add(a.Year, intID)
                        End If
                    Next
```

So adding another value where a.Year already has values assigned to it is where I am having problems. I can do another `lstUID_Year_ID(a.UID).Add(a.Year, intID)` as they key is already present, and writing `lstUID_Year_ID(a.UID).Item(a.Year)` wont allow for another .add clause. So im kind of stuck!

Ive tried writing this with key-value pairs but end up suffering the same problem, i.e. adding values to the nested Year key when it is already present.

Im sure the fix is easy but ive spent a whole day at work toying with it and cant work it out for the life of me.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you'd be better using the uid as the key rather than as the value, or defining the dictionary as key=year and value as a list (of Uid)

Comment: It look to me like you need a `Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Integer)))`. If you don't *need* the speed of a Dictionary, it would be much easier (including readability and maintainability) to use classes instead.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @DavidWilson: the nature of retrieving the data dictates that the UID needs to be the 'primary' key ,so to speak. I will effectively be looking a how many IDs per Year, and whether IDs in one Year match those in another/previous.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: this suggestion might actually work. While speed is not an absolute necessity, as this processing will be occurring in a development environment, it wouldnt be unwelcome! Thanks

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Got it working nicely! Many thanks